# select dropdown thymeleaf if disabled not fetching value in controller

Tags: javascript, html, css, dropdown, spring-thymeleaf

If I use readonly, it grey out the dropdown but I am still able to select values and when I click save I am able to see value got fetched in the controller. But if I use disabled, it grey out and select the correct value (so looks good on UI) but when I click save and check my controller, it doesnt  fetch the value in controller. I need where user is not able to change anything but value should get fetched in controller.

```html
<div>
  <select name="dose" id="dose" class="form-control form-control-sm selective" th:field="*{dose}" th:disabled="disabled">
        <option value="">Choose...</option>
        <option th:each="dose: ${doses}"
          th:selected="${doseSelected == dose}"
          th:text="${dose}"
          th:value="${dose}">
        </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain why you need the value in the controller if the user can't change it anyway?

Comment: Yes, because I need to transfer value from 1 page to another. I need to show the value to user and once I submit the form, I have to still get the value to save to other table.